# magento connect manager not showing installed extensions

Tags: magento-connect

I am unable to see any extension installed in magento in Magento Connect Manager.

Can someone help?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This could be a number of things, but it's most likely a missing, corrupt, or impossible to write to `cache.cfg` file.

When you install an extension via Magento Connect, it's value is saved in the compressed

```
downloader/cache.cfg
```

file.  My guess is this file is missing on your system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alan. But doesn't it create new cache.cfg file automatically? how can we fix? Thanks again.

Comment: I am looking to get list of all modules in Magento connect. Is it possible? Thanks